# C# how to sort my name list by the surname instead of the first name

Tags: c#

I want to sort the list by surname but the code is currently sorting the list by the first name. Most of the stuff I have already googled isn't applicable for me since I haven't learned most those expressions yet.

I don't get how I can make it sort by the surname instead of the first name. I already thought about 2D arrays but I have no idea how they work in combination with sort.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data =
@"Max;Stroll;60
James;Parker;60
Jon;Doe;50
Bob;Dylan;40
Scott;Butler;45
";
            Console.WriteLine(sortNames(data));
        }

        private static string sortNames(string dataList)
        {
            List<string> personList = new List<string>(dataList.Trim().Split("\r\n"));
            personList.Sort();

            string addPerson = "";

            foreach (var item in personList)
            {
                addPerson += item + "\r\n";
            }
            return addPerson;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the overload for List.Sort() [that takes a comparer as a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-int32-system-int32-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))).  You can then pass it a custom comparer that does the right thing.

Comment: First, though, get away from using strings for everything.

Comment: Correct.  To do this well, you will need a `Name` class that separates the name parts into first name and last name properties.

Comment: It would be *a lot* easier if you use objects instead of delimeted strings.  Now would be an ideal time to start learning about custom classes.  To a new developer it may seem like overkill or unnecessarily verbose and difficult, but it ends up making the code *vastly* simpler.  *"Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."* - Eric S. Raymond

Comment: If you use a class to represent a name, you can implement `IComparable<T>` in that class, and the name object will already know how to sort itself properly.

Comment: `IComparable<T>` is for the *natural* order, but because we're talking about an alternative order, a separate `IComparer<T>` implementation would be more appropriate. I would even argue that this data has *no* natural order and should not implement `IComparable<T>` at all. (`IEquatable<T>`, on the other hand, should be fine as there is a natural concept of value equality.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not familiar with classes and OOP principles instead of using strings for everything,
so let us think about a basic solution we just need to do it manually

1- we need your idea of adding each line to personList

2- create another list of surnames concatenated with the index of the line in the personList, to be able to retrieve the whole line not only the surnames

3- sort the list of the surnames.

4- loop on the surnames after sorting, and split each item to retrieve the index of the surname in the original list

5- use this index in the personList to retrieve the whole person's data and then display it.

```
private static string sortNames(string dataList)
{
     List<string> personList = new List<string>(dataList.Trim().Split("\r\n"));
     List<string> surnameList = new List<string>();

     for (int i=0; i<personList.Count; i++)
     {
         string[] personData = personList[i].Split(";"); //surname is located at index = 1
         string surnameAndIndex = personData[1] + " " + i.ToString(); // Stroll 0
         surnameList.Add(surnameAndIndex);
     }

     surnameList.Sort();
     string addPerson = "";
     foreach (var item in surnameList)
     {
          string[] s = item.Split(" "); //index is located at 1 in the personList
          int index = Int32.Parse(s[1]); // converts string to int
          addPerson += personList[index] + "\r\n";
     }
     return addPerson;
}
```

just to be recorded, this is not the best practice at all for that kind of needs
but it is a solution you can use
try to use more data structures and object-oriented programming instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Person class for this instead of strings.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

or with a constructor

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can just sort this string into the Person class (in this case im using the Person class with the constructor)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data =
@"Max;Stroll;60
James;Parker;60
Jon;Doe;50
Bob;Dylan;40
Scott;Butler;45
";
            Person[] persons = CreatePersons(data).OrderBy(x => x.LastName); //Create a person array and then sort it by LastName

            foreach (var person in persons) //Iterate throught the sorted person array
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName}, {person.Age}"); //Print out every person
            }
        }

        private static Person[] CreatePersons(string dataList) //Returns a Person array
        {
            string[] splittedData = dataList.Trim().Split("\r\n"); //Splits the string list by line breaks
    
            var persons = new List<Person>(); //Creates a new List of Persons
            for (int i = 0; i < splittedData.Length; i++) //Iterate throught the splitted data
            {
                string[] splittedPerson = splittedData[i].Split(';'); //Splits the data again to get the firstname, lastname, and age
                persons.Add(new Person(splittedPerson[0], splittedPerson[1], int.Parse(splittedPerson[2]); //Create and add the person to the list
            }

            return persons.ToArray(); //Convert the list to an array and return it
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Age = age;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public int Age { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead `personList.Sort();` use this

```
personList = personList.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(';') + 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach.: the `.Substring` call will allocate and copy a new string for every comparison. Also, it won't work as-expected if a line does not have a `;` character in it.

Comment: Yes, properly CSV should be parsed, loaded into objects or at least arrays, sorted accordingly and then serialized again. But for a smaller sample of data this works fine. Of course, any empty rows need to be either filtered out of the list (perhaps via Where) or have a "condition" added to them during sorting.